# LinkGenerator.GetUriByAction requiring HttpContext even though there is an extension without it

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to use the `GetUriByAction` extension method of `LinkGenerator` to produce a url for a given action.

As you can see below, the intellisense shows two options -- one that requires HttpContext as the first parameter and one that does not.  I'm trying to use the one that does not; however, the compiler continues to complain that my first parameter is not an HttpContext -- even though intellisense shows that it the first parameter is a string.

What do I need to do to use the `GetUriByAction` extension without the HttpContext?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Test Code in my side.

```
<a href="@LinkGenerator.GetUriByAction( "Delete","Home", values: null, "https" , new HostString("localhost", 7214))">test1</a>

<a href="@LinkGenerator.GetUriByAction(
            action:"Index",
            controller: "Home",
            values: new RouteValueDictionary(new { query = "some?query" }),
            scheme:"https",
            host:new HostString("localhost",7025),
            pathBase : new PathString("/Foo/Bar?encodeme?"),
            fragment :new FragmentString("#Fragment?"),
            options :new LinkOptions() { AppendTrailingSlash = true, })">test2</a>
```

[image]

There is no error in my VS2022, it can build/run well in my side, but not in the pages.  Will raise a github issue tomorrow.

[image]

For your suggestion, you can upgrade the VS2022 to latest version first.

Comment: Github issue: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/54054